# How to match 3rd repeated keyword in json string with my keyword in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, instr

I'm able to match the first repeated keyword in json string using INSTR(json_string,'keyword') but trying to figure out how to match 3rd repeated keyword occuring in that json document?

Appreciate if someone can give me a clue here?

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the occurence to the `INSTR` function:

`INSTR(string , substring [, start_position [, occurrence]])`

Take a look at this example:

```
WITH EXAMPLE AS (
  SELECT 'abcabcabc' AS TEST_STRING FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
  INSTR(TEST_STRING, 'a', 1, 1) AS FIRST_ENCOUNTER,
  INSTR(TEST_STRING, 'a', 1, 2) AS SECOND_ENCOUNTER,
  INSTR(TEST_STRING, 'a', 1, 3) AS THIRD_ENCOUNTER
FROM EXAMPLE
```

| FIRST_ENCOUNTER | SECOND_ENCOUNTER | THIRD_ENCOUNTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gmX9B6Na)

Comment: ok thank you..& final thing here.. how to filter and, &, or, keywords within sql to match the keyword. I have 'and' in keyword, '&' in json string.